# Having problems in loading MNIST database

Tags: python, mnist

So i am simply trying to load the MNIST database (which i downloaded) and train
a classifier and then save the training session to a file for future use. I have tried downloading it directly (through fetch_mldata) but my internet seems to be too slow to go that way,so i am trying to read the database by downloading it exteranlly but am getting an error as given below the code. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn import datasets
from skimage.feature import hog
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
import numpy as np
import mlab
import scipy.io

print 'fetching'
dataset = scipy.io.loadmat('mnist-original.mat')

print 'fetched'
features = np.array(dataset.data, 'int16')
labels = np.array(dataset.target, 'int')
ist_hog_fd = []
for feature in features:
    fd = hog(feature.reshape((28, 28)), orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(14, 14), cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=False)
    list_hog_fd.append(fd)
hog_features = np.array(list_hog_fd, 'float64')
clf=LinearSVC()
clf.fit(hog_features,labels)
joblib.dump(clf, "digits_cls.pkl", compress=3)
```

When i run it , i get an error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samad/Red_Queen/v2(ud&ay)/scratch2.py", line 14, in <module>
    features = np.array(dataset.data, 'int16')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'data'
```

To be honest i am not very known to numpy arrays as well as handling .mat
files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So , it took some time but i found a fix anyway.
Instead of using scipy to load the '.mat' extension  file il used the auto downloder or this code to directly download the database:

```
dataset = datasets.fetch_mldata("MNIST Original")
```

and the trick is I placed the externally downloaded file in the cache folder 
of scikit, so it won't have to download it. The path to the cache directory is:

```
~/scikit_learn_data/mldata/
```

And you can download the original mat file from anywhere through a Google search.

But I used the link :
[Link to Download](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amplab/datascience-sp14/master/lab7/mldata/mnist-original.mat)
which may or may not work atm.